# While installing Exchange 2007 sp1 "Exchange organisation does not support this version of Exchange server"

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

First of all, I don't know is this write blog to ask to these types of questions to guide the blog that i can post it there.

I am facing the error "Exchange Organisation does not support this version of exchange server"  at time of installation of exchange server 2007 in the Windows server 2008 Enterprise edition.

I have already installed exchange Server 2010 in the that domain.

The following the image that show the error that i am facing

[image]

I have the checked current Active Directory or Exchange Server schema version by using [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556086)

Using that i got the following information

> "dsquery * cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=india,dc=local -scope base
>   -attr objectVersion"

objectVersion = Windows Server 2008 RTM

CN=ms-Exch-Schema-Version-Pt,cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=india,dc=local -scope base -attr rangeUpper" 
rangeUpper = 14726 ( Exchange server 2010 sp1)

I am attaching the Exchange server setup logs here

Logfile.txt

> [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0]
>   ********************************************** [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0] Starting Microsoft Exchange 2007 Setup [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0]
>   ********************************************** [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0] Operating System version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0] Setup version: 8.1.240.6. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:28 PM] [0] Logged on user: INDIA\administrator. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:28 PM] [0] Command Line Parameter Name='mode', Value='Install'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0] Command Line Parameter Name='sourcedir',
>   Value='C:\Exchange2007'. [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0] Command Line
>   Parameter Name='fromsetup', Value=''. [5/31/2013 3:04:28 PM] [0]
>   ExSetupUI was started with the following command: '-mode:install
>   -sourcedir:C:\Exchange2007 /FromSetup'. [5/31/2013 3:04:29 PM] [0] Setup is choosing the domain controller to use [5/31/2013 3:04:29 PM]
>   [0] Setup is choosing a local domain controller... [5/31/2013 3:04:31
>   PM] [0] Setup has chosen the local domain controller
>   NewDelhi.india.local for initial queries [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0]
>   PrepareAD has either not been run or has not replicated to the domain
>   controller used by Setup. Setup will attempt to use the Schema Master
>   domain controller NewDelhi.india.local [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] The
>   schema master domain controller is available [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM]
>   [0] The schema master domain controller is in the local domain; setup
>   will use NewDelhi.india.local [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup is
>   choosing a global catalog... [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup has
>   chosen the global catalog server NewDelhi.india.local. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup will use the domain controller
>   'NewDelhi.india.local'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup will use the
>   global catalog 'NewDelhi.india.local'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0]
>   Exchange configuration container for the organization is 'CN=Microsoft
>   Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=india,DC=local'. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:31 PM] [0] No Exchange organization container was found for the
>   organization. Message: 'Could not find the Organization Container.'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup will search for an Exchange Server
>   object for the local machine with name 'PONDY'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM]
>   [0] No Exchange Server with identity 'PONDY' was found. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:31 PM] [0] The following roles are unpacked:  [5/31/2013 3:04:31
>   PM] [0] The following roles are installed:  [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0]
>   The local server does not have any Exchange files installed.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Setup will use the path 'C:\Exchange2007'
>   for installing Exchange. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] The server is
>   cluster type: 'None'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] The requested cluster
>   type: 'None'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] The installation mode is set
>   to: 'Install'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Exchange organization name
>   is required for this mode. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Active Directory
>   Initialization status : 'True'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0] Schema
>   Update Required Status : 'False'. [5/31/2013 3:04:31 PM] [0]
>   Organization Configuration Update Required Status : 'True'. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:31 PM] [0] Domain Configuration Update Required Status : 'False'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Applying default role selection state
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup is determining what
>   organization-level operations to perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0]
>   Setup has detected a missing value. Setup is adding the value
>   PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup will run from
>   path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'. [5/31/2013 3:04:32
>   PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 4 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:32
>   PM] [0] Setup is determining what organization-level operations to
>   perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup has detected a missing
>   value. Setup is adding the value PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup will run from path
>   'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0]
>   InstallModeDataHandler has 5 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0]
>   Setup is determining what organization-level operations to perform.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup has detected a missing value. Setup
>   is adding the value PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0]
>   Setup will run from path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 6 DataHandlers
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup is determining what
>   organization-level operations to perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0]
>   Setup has detected a missing value. Setup is adding the value
>   PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:32 PM] [0] Setup will run from
>   path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'. [5/31/2013 3:04:32
>   PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 6 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:32
>   PM] [0] RootDataHandler has 1 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0]
>   Setup is determining what organization-level operations to perform.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0] Setup has detected a missing value. Setup
>   is adding the value PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0]
>   Setup will run from path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 5 DataHandlers
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0] Setup is determining what
>   organization-level operations to perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0]
>   Setup has detected a missing value. Setup is adding the value
>   PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0] Setup will run from
>   path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'. [5/31/2013 3:04:44
>   PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 4 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:44
>   PM] [0] Setup is determining what organization-level operations to
>   perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0] Setup has detected a missing
>   value. Setup is adding the value PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013
>   3:04:44 PM] [0] Setup will run from path
>   'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'. [5/31/2013 3:04:44 PM] [0]
>   InstallModeDataHandler has 1 DataHandlers [5/31/2013 3:04:46 PM] [0]
>   Setup is determining what organization-level operations to perform.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:46 PM] [0] Setup has detected a missing value. Setup
>   is adding the value PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:46 PM] [0]
>   Setup will run from path 'C:\Exchange2007\Setup\ServerRoles\Common'.
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:46 PM] [0] InstallModeDataHandler has 4 DataHandlers
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:48 PM] [0] Validating options for the 0 requested
>   roles [5/31/2013 3:04:48 PM] [0] Validating options for the 0
>   requested roles [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM] [0] Setup is determining what
>   organization-level operations to perform. [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM] [0]
>   Setup has detected a missing value. Setup is adding the value
>   PrepareOrganization. [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM] [0] Because the value was
>   specified, setup is setting the argument OrganizationName to the value
>   First Organization. [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM] [0] **************
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM] [0] Setup will run the task 'test-setuphealth'
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Setup launched task 'test-setuphealth
>   -DomainController 'NewDelhi.india.local' -DownloadConfigurationUpdates $true -ExchangeVersion '8.1.240.6' -Roles 'Global' -ScanType
>   'PrecheckInstall' -SetupRoles 'Global' -PrepareOrganization $true'
>   [5/31/2013 3:04:53 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Beginning processing. [5/31/2013 3:05:24
>   PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) [ERROR] The Exchange organization does not support this
>   version of Exchange Server. [5/31/2013 3:05:24 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Ending
>   processing. [5/31/2013 3:05:24 PM] [0] ************** [5/31/2013
>   3:05:24 PM] [0] Setup will run the task 'test-setuphealth' [5/31/2013
>   3:05:24 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Setup launched task 'test-setuphealth
>   -DomainController 'NewDelhi.india.local' -DownloadConfigurationUpdates $false -ExchangeVersion '8.1.240.6' -Roles 'Mailbox' -ScanType
>   'PrecheckInstall' -SetupRoles 'AdminTools','Mailbox' -CreatePublicDB
>   $true -TargetDir 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server'
>   -IISInstalled $true'   [5/31/2013 3:05:24 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Beginning processing. [5/31/2013 3:05:27 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) [ERROR] The Exchange
>   organization does not support this version of Exchange Server.
>   [5/31/2013 3:05:27 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkhD.png) Ending processing. [5/31/2013 3:05:40 PM]
>   [0] End of Setup [5/31/2013 3:05:40 PM] [0]
>
> ---

Please suggest me how to install the exchange server 2007 SP1 on the domain that has exchange server 2010 sp1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you can not add MS Exchange 2007 in an organization that is running MS Exchange 2010 (previously an upgraded version of Exchange server 2007). Yes, othis is true that MS Exchange 2010 support co-existence but in a case when MS Exchange organization is having lower version not a higher version from what you are going to install.

Hope you understand the reason :)

Regards,

Adnan.